# NuCanoe 12' vs. NuFontier 12'

Tags: fishing, kayaks, canoes

I'm in the market for a kayak that will be used for inshore fishing, paddling, and occasionally hunting.  Can anyone help me with the differences between the [NuCanoe 12'](http://www.nucanoe.com/models/nucanoe/) and the [NuFontier 12'](http://www.nucanoe.com/models/frontier/)?

Comment: You can hunt in a kayak?

Comment: @Stereotypical for sure you just need to make sure you follow the local hunting laws for hunting in a boat.

Comment: Voting to delete, closed question, no answer, no added value to the site.